# Weird grey edges on searchbar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, searchbar

I have added a `UISeachBar` to a view and for some reason it has these weird grey edges which appear to be behind the search bar. Where do they come from / how do I get rid of them?

[image]

```
searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: self.frame.width-20, height: 25))
searchBar.delegate = self
self.addSubview(searchBar)
```

Comment: Does your `view` have a background color? Did you try `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Comment: Do you have any code or storyboard screenshots that you can provide?